# Foreach cycle return randly changed values

Tags: php, foreach, cycle

I have some .ini file which I can't change. It looks like:

```
01code6=77
01name6=G 650 Xcountry/Xmoto/Xchallenge (K15) [V] [77]
01type6=Bike
01code7=E3
01name7=i3 od 07/13 (I01) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [E3]
01type7=Car
01code8=E8
01name8=i8 kupé od 03/14 (I12) [V] [3D] [E8]
01type8=Car
01code9=80
01name9=K 100 - K 1200 RS / K1 od 04/84 [V] [80]
01type9=Bike
```

And code to parse it looks like:

```
public function pasrseString($path)
{
    $ini = parse_ini_file($path, false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
    foreach(array_chunk($ini, 3, true) as $data) 
    {                                                   
            // $data is an array of just the 3 that are related
            $mcode = substr(array_keys($data)[0], 0, 2);
            $nameLine = array_values($data)[1];
            $typeLine = array_values($data)[2];
            $vehicle = array_values($data)[0];
            echo $vehicle;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $typeLine;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $nameLine;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $mcode;                                
    }
}
```

As you can see in .ini files tehre are always 3 lines for 1 vehicle,

> - first line with code
> - second line with name
> - third line with vehicle_type

My script can get to correct values dispite this fact my cycle fail somehow because there are wrong values in variabiles. So for example if i run this cycle on whole file 
echo $vehicle for some vehicles return vehicle data, for another vehicles it return vehicle type, for another it return mcode, dispite the fact that in file there are always order like this.

I am really confuse in that WHAT I AM DOING WRONG in this cycle, can someone help find a solution?

p.s. order of values are changing if i use bigger or smaller value in `foreach(array_chunk($ini, 3, true) as $data)`

**EDIT**:
I found out there are some blanked data in code, for example

```
01code0=
01name0=
```

so example code with blanked values can looks like:

```
00code46=65
00name46=TT kupé od 07/14 (FV) [V] [S] [3D] [65]
00type46=Car
00code47=45
00name47=TT od 08/06 (8J) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [45]
00type47=Car
01code0=
01name0=
01code1=M2
01name1=C 600 Sport/C 650 GT od 01/12 (K18/0131) (K19/0133) [V] [M2]
01type1=Bike
01code2=70
01name2=F 650 GS / F 800 GS od mod. ´08 [V] [70]
01type2=Bike
01code3=84
```

there just like 5 blanked values in whole document so really not many

Comment: why do you change value in array_chunk?

Comment: I don't, they change without my decision.  I need to have always in one variabile one kind of value. But I afraid I did some crazy mystake and my cycle not working correctly

Comment: i as k about this * i use bigger or smaller value*

Answer (score 1):

a bit of php magic later:

```
$vehicles = array_map(function($vs){ 
    return array_combine(array('code','name','type'),$vs);
}, array_chunk(parse_ini_string($x,false,INI_SCANNER_RAW),3));
```

parse ini, chunkify, map over chunks converting positions to names

full code:

```
$x = <<<EOD
01code6=77
01name6=G 650 Xcountry/Xmoto/Xchallenge (K15) [V] [77]
01type6=Bike
01code7=E3
01name7=i3 od 07/13 (I01) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [E3]
01type7=Car
01code8=E8
01name8=i8 kupé od 03/14 (I12) [V] [3D] [E8]
01type8=Car
01code9=80
01name9=K 100 - K 1200 RS / K1 od 04/84 [V] [80]
01type9=Bike
EOD;

$vehicles = array_map(function($vs){ 
    return array_combine(array('code','name','type'),$vs);
}, array_chunk(parse_ini_string($x,false,INI_SCANNER_RAW),3));

var_dump($vehicles); // over which you can iterate to produce the output
/*
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "77"
    ["name"]=>
    string(46) "G 650 Xcountry/Xmoto/Xchallenge (K15) [V] [77]"
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "Bike"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "E3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(41) "i3 od 07/13 (I01) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [E3]"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "Car"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "E8"
    ["name"]=>
    string(37) "i8 kupé od 03/14 (I12) [V] [3D] [E8]"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "Car"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["name"]=>
    string(40) "K 100 - K 1200 RS / K1 od 04/84 [V] [80]"
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "Bike"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: Hi @birdspider, thank you for your answer. It actualy looks cool. so +1! May I just know how can I get to each "car" individualy?

I did :
foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
{
 echo $vehicle['code'];
 echo "<br>";
}
And it sometimes echo code and sometimes type and sometimes name

Comment: @Andurit: depends on what you mean with`individualy`, right now you can use `$vehicles[3]` to get the 4th vehicle, etc...

Comment: @Andurit: so `sometimes type and sometimes name` means: the imput file fields are not sorted , even if your sample suggests so ? - you could have said that

Comment: I am looking to file again, they are always sorted same way, just noticed sometimes there are blanked "data", like:  01code0=
01name0=  Can this have some connection with it?

Comment: sorry for that, to be more specific here is port of input and part of output where it change from "name" to "type" 
http://pastebin.com/dZEx4siA